# Set routing metrics for static IPs with systemd-networkd?

Tags: networking, systemd, routing, systemd-networkd, metric

I recently set up a server with its network managed directly by `systemd-networkd` (nuked `netplan.io` and Network Manager) and gave it static IPs like this:

`/etc/systemd/network/10-ethernet.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.2/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=192.168.1.1
```

After restarting `systemd-networkd.service`, default routes look like this:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto static
default via 172.16.0.1 dev eno2 proto static
default via 172.31.255.1 dev eno3 proto static
                                               ^^^
```

Because there are multiple NICs and I want to make `eno1` the preferred one, I want the routes laid out like this:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
default via 172.16.0.1 dev eno2 proto static metric 300
default via 172.31.255.1 dev eno3 proto static metric 500
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Without the `metric` value, it default to 0, meaning all routes have the same priority (highest), which I want to avoid.

I've tried this setting:

```
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.1.1
Metric=100
```

But it only generates an *extra* route with the desired metric while the original ones (missing `metric`) still remaining.

I'm running on Systemd 240. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Wait, I've started a bounty, but maybe I misunderstand the question. What happens if you only specify one of the two `Gateway`s, on either `[Route]` or `[Network]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this thread you can see the developers talking about how things work vs. how things should work: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/928

They give a couple examples:

Under the Route tag

```
[Route]
Destination=192.168.0.0/24
Metric=2048
```

Under the DHCP tag

```
[DHCP]
RouteMetric=1024
```

It is explained that:

> subnet routes are configured with no metric via address_configure in
>   networkd-address.c when obtaining an IP and dhcp-provided routes with
>   metric are processed later via link_set_dhcp_routes in
>   networkd-dhcp4.c

Further there is a caveat:

> the RouteMetric works for routed packets, but not for those that
>   remain on the local subnet

It's possible that the exact functionality you want doesn't exist yet as the ticket I cited is currently open. Feel free to give feedback directly to the developers and join the discussion if you think you have an idea about how this should be working.